# Grow on load animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying the recreate this image grow when the page is loaded. I can't find a tutorial or many examples anywhere.

Here you can see the example animation on the image: https://dribbble.com/shots/5275648-Beaten-Path

Can anyone help me out with the name of the animation or a way of creating it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: There are so many animations in place on your image. This popular library: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/ is a good place to start, see fadeInUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely just a CSS Animation, consider checking out this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/t1mwillis/pen/LJMJzg) or the attached snippet.

Each image should have a "frame" that is the same size as the image.

Then specify a set of `@keyframes` to describe your intended motion.

Apply those `@keyframes` to your image to get the intended result.

```css
div#frame {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromBottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes slideInFromBottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know whether there are any plug-ins that can replicate this on wordpress?

Comment: @JordanKellett, I don't, sorry!